# How to make a foreach variable in plpgsql NEW or OLD

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

You can make something like:

```
foreach m slice 1 IN array NEW.*
loop
RAISE NOTICE 'var: %', m;
END LOOP;
```

or,

```
FOR i IN NEW LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'var: %', i;
END LOOP
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 5):

[`NEW` and `OLD` are special ***record*** variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) in trigger functions. You cannot loop through them like through arrays.

One way to loop through columns of a (well-known) record or row: transform to `json` or `jsonb`, and then:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   js  jsonb := to_jsonb(NEW);
   col text;
BEGIN
   FOR col IN SELECT * FROM jsonb_object_keys(js)
   LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE '%: %', col, js->>col;
   END LOOP;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```